# sql query containing php variables does not work

Tags: php, mysql, variables, sql-insert

Could someone tell me what is wrong with my query?
I omitted some fields in table_name because I will not use them for now, may be later.

EDITED:
$FILTER_PARAMETERS = "$variable1 $variable2 $varible3... ";

where $variable1 $variable2 $varible3... are numbers, and I want to insert them in the same fielde separated by coma, like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['variable1'])){
    $variable1= ($_POST['variable1'].', ');}
```

If I echo $FILTER_PARAMETERS = "$variable1 $variable2 $varible3... "; , I get

1012, 1025, 1036,

just like I would like it to be inside the `filter_parameters` field.

My query is this one:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `database_name`.`table_name` (
`id` ,
`field1` ,
`field2` ,
`field3` ,
`field4` ,
`field5` ,
`field6` ,
`field7` ,
`field8` ,
`field9` ,
`field10` ,
`field11` ,
`field12` ,
`field13` ,
`field14` ,
`field15` ,
`field16` ,
`field17` ,
`field18` ,
`field19` ,
`field20` ,
`filter_parameters` ,
`field22` ,
`field23` ,
`field24`
) 

VALUES (NULL, '$field1', '$field2', '$field3', '$field4', '', '$field6', '', '', '$field9', '$field10', '$field11', '$field12', '$field13', '', '', '', '', '$field18', '$field19', '$field20', '$FILTER_PARAMETERS', '$field22', '$field23', '');";
```

This query does not insert data in any of fields in database. Any ideas? Thank you.

EDITE:

May be the problem is with $FILTER_PARAMETERS?

Comment: Are those variables `$field1, $field2 ...` Filled with values?

Comment: You are not defining the variables anywhere. Therefore they are all null / blank.

Comment: if the query does not enter blank values than you must get some sql error.. do you get any sql error.. check the logs maybe

Comment: ALWAYS `echo` your query when it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I send values by $_POST, define variables $field1, $field2 ...  and echo those $field1, $field2 ... So, they are not blank.

Comment: please! it don't care if the variables are empty mysql will ever insert everything inside `'` (single quotes) if the `VALUES` count is equal to the `column` count

Comment: May we look at your actual code that does the querying?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I edited my question, please have a look

Comment: @user2170133 - you're not doing any db connection?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld db connection is OK, I select some data from db for this query without any problems

Comment: @user2170133 - I can't see you execute the query? (How is it executed?)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld you mean this:  $query (in my question) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave out the ID field if it's set to auto-increment. Also you should leave a default value on the fields in MySQL that you want to be populated with '' instead of running it through the query each time. If you have a value, then put it there, or leave it out if you don't intend to update or insert it.

```
$mysqli_conn = new mysqli($server_host, $user, $password, "database_name");

$mysqli_query = "INSERT INTO table_name (
`field1` ,
`field2` ,
`field3` ,
`field4` ,
`field6` ,
`field9` ,
`field10` ,
`field11` ,
`field12` ,
`field13` ,
`field18` ,
`field19` ,
`field20` ,
`field21` ,
`field22` ,
`field23` 
) 

VALUES ('$field1', '$field2', '$field3', '$field4', '$field6', '$field9', '$field10', '$field11', '$field12', '$field13', '$field18', '$field19', '$field20', '$field21', '$field22', '$field23')";

$mysqli_result_set = $mysqli_conn->query($mysqli_query);
```

Comment: Removed id and NULL, and left out unnecessary fields and the semicolon at the end. Still does not work

Comment: did you create the connection like i did with $mysqli_conn, define the database to use, and execute the statement using the $mysqli_result_set and the connection class query function as I demonstrated?

Comment: The query you posted with your original code is just defining a string variable. It still needs to be executed by the class for mysql.

Comment: There is no problem with db connection, I pull data from database and use for the query I am trying to execute.

Comment: This line in my code executes the Insert statement `$mysqli_result_set = $mysqli_conn->query($mysqli_query);`

Comment: Try `echo '<pre>' .  print_r($mysqli_result_set) . '</pre>';` to see what is happening when the query is executed and what the response from MySQL is.

Comment: I changed the connection, created like you did, and it worked :) thank you

Answer (score -1):

at the end of you query

```
22', '$field23', '');";
```

you're not closing right, change it by this:

```
22', '$field23', '')");
```

you are missing a right parentheses `)` and delete the first semicolon `;` just leave the last

## EDIT

This is your query without the values and columns

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `database_name`.`table_name` () VALUES ();";
```

just remove the semicolon inside the double quote:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `database_name`.`table_name` () VALUES ()";
```

Comment: Why do you think a closing parenthesis would be missing AFTER the end of this text string?

Comment: An extra paranthesis would create an error. But the semicolon at the end of the query should not be there.

Comment: It gives error if I change the end this way. I think the problem is not here, because I inserted data directly with phpMyAdmin, and copy-pasted the query. But still does not work.

Comment: if you have your id column set to auto_increment remove `id` form the column list and NULL from your VALUES list

Comment: sorry @Jocelyn I hadn't realized that he was using an unnecessary variable to set his query